# Bash - format .txt file into pover pivot form

Tags: linux, bash

txt file called `without_Commas.txt`. The content looks like this:

```
User1 = dsa jhg asfd
User2 = ikjl retzg
User3 = ölkjdshf
...
User400 = gt345 234gt 7fgd zhju ertzui
```

I need to format this data to look like this:

```
User1   dsa 
User1   jhg
User1   asdf
User2   ikjl
User2   retzg
User3   ölkjdshf
...
User400   gt345
User400   234gt
User400   7fgd
User400   zhju
User400   ertzui
```

Is there a way to do this?

Kind Regards Elias

Comment: Use `awk`. On each line, loop from 3 to NF to get each word after `=`, printing $1 and the current word.

Comment: Thanks, can you give me a quick start for that?

Comment: `for (i = 3; i <= NF; i++)`

Comment: Thanks, could you help me out a bit more? I don´t really know how to use `awk` or a loop.

Comment: @Elias : Since you are asking for a bash solution: (1) Use a proper #! line to mark your script as bash. (2) Loop over the lines of the input file. (3) Break each line on the equal sign. (4) Split the right-hand-side into words. (5) For each of the words create an output line. Isn't this an obvious sequence of steps? If you don't know bash well, think about how you would solve this in any programming language you are familiar with.

Comment: OK, I will try it. Wish me luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '{for (i = 3; i <= NF; i++) print $1, $i}' without_Commas.txt > output.txt
```

On each line, this loops over all the field numbers starting with the third field. Then it prints the first field (`$1`) followed by the current field in the loop (`$i`).